# Are there the equivalent of Attacks of Opportunity in the Mythus Game

Tags: combat, dangerous-journeys

Can anyone tell me whether there is an equivalent of Attacks of Opportunity in the Dangerous Journeys Mythus RPG?  I thought there was but have searched through the rulebook and can't find any.

Comment: There are a lot of things I like about the Dangerous Journeys: Mythus RPG but the way the books have the rules set out isn't one of them.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was, since the invention of opportunity attacks as a distinct category and rule came from an divergent and unrelated branch in the development of D&D. I'd be looking sooner for an "engaged" rule in the style of his earlier, wargames-inspired designs. I wouldn't expect him to borrow from WotC, considering everything else in Mythus seems to be "like AD&D, but moreso."

Answer (score 1):

No. There are no attacks of opportunity in Dangerous Journeys. If you are using the 30 beat CT attacks of opportunity would be useless and unbalanced.